# How can I get revisionId from Slide API without editor's grant?

Tags: slide, google-slides-api, google-slides

How can I get revisionId from Slide API without editor's grant?
**It's not possible, by** [Google Slide API](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations)

Someone tried to share a document using a "Service Account (key)"? Is it possible?